# Customer based Encryption, storing of sensitive names

Tags: encryption

Will try and keep this simple, basically we are developing an MVC /SQL server web application that would be used but multiple Schools , our customer does not want to store/hold Student names ANYWHERE in there environment. Obviously when a school logs into the system we really need to display student names.

What sort of encryption methods are there ? is this possible at all ? / realistic ?

Only method i have thought of is for each school to generate there own "key" which is used to encrypt / decrypt data going to and from the browser, this key would have to be stored locally on device some how ?

or find 3rd party company that would store data ... ?

ideas ? options ?

Comment: You could use seperated databases for every school, The most logical way to me is what you suggested. Give every school a key that you store with the school user. The only way they can get this is by login in with the right username/pass. With this key they can decrypt the names

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL server, it can encrypt by itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/sql-server-encryption

Otherwise depending on the programming language you can use an encryption algorithm like AES. This really depends on your development stack. Another option is to not use real names but only student id.